# Meaning of English phrase - "right on the water"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does the phrase "right on the water" have a different meaning in the below dialogue?

> Man: Who hasn't dreamed of living right on the water?
>   Woman: Oh, it's so pretty.
>   Man: You are right on the water.
>   Woman: Wow.
>   Man: That's unreal.
>   Woman: This is spectacular.

Comment: Is this a real estate agent showing waterfront property to a couple?

Comment: I think the meaning is literal: http://marinavillage.co.za/

Comment: Or maybe showing a houseboat? Or a house on a pier?

Comment: A "different meaning" *from what*? (What would be "the same meaning"?)

Answer (score -1):

'***RIGHT***' is an adverb here and means:
"Exactly; precisely
(For example: right here.)"
(According to Collin's Dictionary
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/right?s=t)

So, they speak about  some accommodation which is located exactly on the riverbank, the coast or water surface.

Comment: This answer strikes me as overly precise.  Are you suggesting that a building built further back than say the high tide marker, or not on a pier or seawall on the water can never be described as "right on the water"?

Comment: There may be some exaggeration, of course.

Comment: @user662852: Your mileage may vary. Expressions like these aren't meant to be accurate to six decimal places.

Comment: @robusto and 307254 - my hangup is on the word "exactly" in the answer, since, to me, "exactly" is to all the decimal places :D  I had started and abandoned an answer when this appeared based on the differential waterfront qualities of vacation rentals on North Carolina's Outer Banks, which includes {Oceanfront, Oceanside, "between the highways", Soundside, Soundfront} which is in it's way also overly precise, but the fact is thousands of dollars ride on the distinction.

Comment: "Exactly" and "precisely" can be used in an exaggerated or hyperbolic sense as well. Your hangup is, well, your hangup. When I bought my latest house I told everyone it was "perfect" even though there were some things that were not 100% perfect. Nobody came over with a measuring tape.